# Passing Text around defs

Tags: python, list

I want to pass the text that comes from this list to see what is contained in it.

The def used is this:

```
def getTotal(self) :
        total = []
        for i in range(self.List.getItemCount()) :
            total.append(self.List.getItemText(i))
        return total
```

In my main I have this:

```
msg+=self.getTotal()
```

What's the correct way of adding to `msg` so it'll print correctly to the screen?

Expected output:

```
['Object1', 'Object2']
```

Comment: May be this is what you want:
`for s in self.getTotal():msg+=s`

Comment: Can you put your input and expected output.

Comment: OK added it. Would also like a way of separating the print

Comment: what you are printing is a list, what about making msg as list() ? and extend the return. `msg.extend(self.getTottal())`

Comment: What do you mean by extending the return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to add the list to a string message. In that case you need to use `str()` to convert the list into a string:

```
msg += str(self.getTotal())
```

You can print the objects in the list by doing:

```
msg += ', '.join(self.getTotal())
```

Comment: So it now returns ['Object1', 'Object2'], how would I then get the message just to print out the individual parts without changing the def getTotal ?

Comment: @fiz: now updated. What version of Python do you have?

Comment: That's a very good question. I think it is 2.6, the problem is python is the back-end to all of this

Comment: I basically just want to grab that Object1 and Object 2 so I can have, `if item in getTotal()==Object1:` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you expect the output to be but would

```
output_str = ', '.join(self.getTotal())
```

Answer (score 0):

assumed the list contains numbers I would do it like this:

```
print msg + ' ' +  str(self.getTotal())
```

If you want to save the whole content in the message first:

```
msg += ' ' + str(self.getTotal())
print msg
```